# Let $N$, $K$ be sub-modules of $M$ with $I=\mathrm{Ann}(N)$, $J=\mathrm{Ann}(K)$. Show $I+J$ is a proper subset of $\mathrm{Ann}(N \cap K)$.

Tags: modules

Let $N$ and $K$ be sub-modules of $M$ with $I=\operatorname{Ann}(N)$ and $J=\operatorname{Ann}(K)$. Show that $I+J$ is a proper subset of $\operatorname{Ann}(N \cap K)$.

Comment: When $N=K$, for example, there's equality $I+J= \text{Ann}(N\cap K)$. Perhaps the word "proper" is redundant?

Answer (score 2):

For any $i\in I$ we have that $in=0$ for all $n\in N$.  For any $j\in J$ we have that $jk=0$ for all $k\in K$.  Now take $i+j$.  Look at $x\in N\cap K$.  $ix=0$ because $x\in N$.  $jx=0$ because $x\in K$.  Thus $(i+j)x=ix+jx=0$ so $i+j\in \text{Ann}(N\cap K)$ so $I+J\leqslant \text{Ann}(N\cap K)$.

I don't see why it should be true in general that $I+J$ should be proper.  Aside from the obvious case with $N=K$, we have for example from where $N$ is a submodule of $K$ (where $I+J$ is sometimes proper but not always).

Comment: Or take the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z}.$ Take $M = R,$ take $N$ to be the ideal $2R$ and $K$ to be the ideal $3R.$ Then $I +J$ contains the unit $5,$ so is all of $R.$